# VBA using Index/Match to find and replace specific values on target spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

Updating information on an already populated target sheet which contains a particular numerical string in a source sheet.  Using INDEX/MATCH

I've successfully done this using Excel-VLOOKUP in Vba but I need to use INDEX/MATCH because current code is too slow.

Im currently using this method, but it is way too slow.

[Sub faster_reviewercomments()
    Dim lngRow As Long

```
On Error Resume Next
lngRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Worksheets("REVIEW SHEET").Range("C2"), Worksheets("SAVEDWORK").Range("b2:b15000"), 0)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Search failed "
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo 0
Worksheets("SavedWork").Range("b2:b15000").Cells(lngRow, 18) = Sheets("Review Sheet").Range("d18")
```

End Sub]

On the Target sheet (Sheet2) there is old information and I need to replace some of the data with updated information that I will be inputting on sheet1 using a Claim Number as the Match.

For example, if claim #123's old information on sheet2 is "OPEN" under the Status Column, I want to enter that claim number on Sheet1, type "CLOSED" and have that change on sheet2 to reflect the new status I've just assigned to it.

There are over 10,000 rows on sheet 2, so some of the code i have tried using vba and the Vlookup takes over 1 minute to update each record.

I'm hoping something like this is possible with INDEX MATCH to see if it's faster.

Edit #2:  Ok, I consolidated all the lookups into 1.  Now it looks like this.  I timed it, and it takes 37-38 Seconds to complete (which may still be unacceptable to boss lady).  there are really only 3500 excel rows populated but I have it at 10K in the code to give it room for expansion.

there will really never be duplicate claim numbers in that sheet, so i wonder if there's a way to make it stop looping when it finds the desired target in that list.

Sub UPDATE_RECORD()
    Dim lngRow As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    lngRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Worksheets("REVIEW SHEET").Range("C2"), Worksheets("SAVEDWORK").Range("b2:b10000"), 0)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Search failed "
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Worksheets("SavedWork").Range("b2:b10000").Cells(lngRow, 18) = Sheets("Review Sheet").Range("D18")
    Worksheets("SavedWork").Range("b2:b10000").Cells(lngRow, 19) = Sheets("Review Sheet").Range("D19")
    Worksheets("SavedWork").Range("b2:b10000").Cells(lngRow, 20) = Sheets("Review Sheet").Range("D20")
    Worksheets("SavedWork").Range("b2:b10000").Cells(lngRow, 23) = Sheets("Review Sheet").Range("F22")
    Worksheets("SavedWork").Range("b2:b10000").Cells(lngRow, 22) = Sheets("Review Sheet").Range("D22")
    Worksheets("SavedWork").Range("b2:b10000").Cells(lngRow, 16) = Sheets("Review Sheet").Range("D2")
End Sub

Comment: `There are over 10,000 rows`  am I missing the loop?  This should be quick as it is a one off.

Comment: `10,000 rows` ... `taking over 1 min`.... turn off auto calcs and it will fly.  `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`. Turn back on again after it writes the new value if needed

Comment: If this specific code is slow you need to check for events or volatile calculations.  This code would happen nearly instantly.

Comment: If you are looping 10,000 times, then look into using variant arrays.

Comment: what @ScottCraner said. This action would take under a second (more like less than half a second to complete). check this out https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/

Comment: IF you are updating elements on the same line then 'yes', you should copy and paste that last line of the routine (five times) and adjust the references. There would be no need to do repeated searches for the same information. There are efficiences to be had but it is hard to imagine them making a notable difference in such a small routine. One thing you could consider is to sort your 'index' column so you can use a more efficient search method in the 'match' function (ie using '-1' or '1' instead of '0')

Comment: I did a small test on time. I created 15,000 claim records (ie JE94040682) and did a thousand lookups on that data. Hard to tell as it was quick so I upped it to 15,000 look ups (using 'match') and it came out at 15 sec. So 5 or six lookups is not the issue... As Scott Holtzman mentioned above, you are probably triggering workbook calculations which would explain the lag.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! Really appreciate it!